# Get name of current used allocator in Rust program

Tags: rust, allocator

How can I write a Rust function:

```rust
fn current_allocator_name() -> &str { ... }
```

which will return name of current used allocator?

---

For example if my program use jemalloc:

```rust
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: jemallocator::Jemalloc = jemallocator::Jemalloc;
```

Then this function will return string "jemalloc"